# Fill path in WPF through code leaves a jaggered edge

Tags: c#, wpf

I create a Path in WPF using C# and set the Stroke which results in a smooth outline. When I Fill the Path without the Stroke I get a jaggered edge on the right hand side of the rendering. Putting in the Stroke hides this edge, but adds extra width to the shape which I don't want.

This is my code:

```
Path myPath = new Path();
SolidColorBrush colorBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(57, 57, 57));
myPath.Fill = colorBrush;
//myPath.Stroke = colorBrush;
myPath.Data = Geometry.Parse("M 0,0 H 60 C 100,0 120,20 120,60 L 60,120 C 20,120 0,100 0,60 L 0,0");
```

The result of this code is below with the shape on the left from the code above and the right from the code above only using the Stroke.

[image: Jaggered edge with fill]

Has anyone seen this before or may know why it is happening? I actually get the same with objects in XAML. I am using VS2012 running in a VPC just incase that may contribute.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: I don't have this issue with your code. My guess is some scaling issue in application or OS.

Comment: I don't think the Fill-Property draws a perfect path close to yours but fills the path with rectangles. Simply scale your Canvas instead of setting the border to no color?

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your responses. I feel like a fool, as Thomas says it works fine. Turns out to be the PC I was using. I checked this on three other PCs and it renders perfectly. Soo many wasted hours.

Answer (score 0):

Just so we can close this post. This turned out to be a rendering problem with the version of Windows (VPC) I was using, not having enough processing power.

If I can take anything from this experience, if your code is correct but doing something that no one else in the world is experiencing then maybe its your environment. Try on another computer and if the problem still exists then see your 'SO'Doctor.

Answer (score -1):

Like i said in the comment to your post.

> I don't think the Fill-Property draws a perfect path close to yours
>   but fills the path with rectangles. Simply scale your Canvas instead
>   of setting the border to no color?

```
<Canvas Width="30" Height="30" Clip="F1 M 0,0L 0,30L 30,30L 30,0L 0,0">
    <Path Width="30" Height="30" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#393939" Data="M 0,0 H 60 C 100,0 120,20 120,60 L 60,120 C 20,120 0,100 0,60 L 0,0"/>
</Canvas>
```

Comment: Hi Marc, I actually tried to use the Clip path and it did fix the right hand side, but then the left hand side became jaggered. As explained in my answer it was a rendering problem in the end. Thanks for your help though. :)